# Leaving Germany (and Europe) with an almost-expired PhD student residence permit

Tags: germany, student-visa

A friend of mine currently lives in Germany on a PhD student residence permit, which expires on March 31st, 2024. The friend had a falling out with their project; as a result, while they still keep their student status, it will not be renewed.

Is their residence permit still supposed to be valid? If the student leaves Germany (and Europe) for important family-related stuff for a week in February, will they be allowed to return to Germany despite their residence permit will be close to expiring by then?

Comment: Have they informed German immigration about the dropout

Comment: If the reason to issue the residence permit becomes invalid, your permit expires after 3 months (from the date of the end of contract or student status), so your friend might be overstaying already.

Comment: We went over this with the friend, and the added context changes the question, probably putting it in the realm of speculation. Should I close it now?